# Android Как отобразить в WebView только div id="main-content"

Tags: html, android-webview

Научите, пожалуйста, как из всей html страницы вывести в WebView содержимое только `div id="main-content"`.

Если я правильно понял, то тут есть 3 пути:

1. Парсить всю страницу, а потом собрать из полученного новый html
2. Использовать JavaScript и показать только то, что мне нужно (`div id="main-content"`).
3. Использовать JavaScript и спрятать всё то, что мне НЕ нужно (`header class="mh-header"` и `aside class="mh-sidebar"`).

Так как я совсем начинающий "разработчик", то весьма смутно представляю как это сделать. Парсить и пересобирать HTML это для меня пока очень сложно.
Хотелось бы посмотреть на пример решения вторым или третьим способом. Уважаемые гуру - поделитесь крупицей своих знаний. :)

Answer (score 1):

Нашел ответ на [этой странице](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32828230/how-remove-header-from-webview-on-android).
Этот ответ подходит для третьего варианта решения.

Я использовал следующий код:

```
 webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +
        "var head = document.getElementsByTagName('header')[0];"
                + "head.parentNode.removeChild(head);" +
                "})()");
 webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +
                "var head = document.getElementsByTagName('aside')[0];"
                + "head.parentNode.removeChild(head);" +
                "})()");
```

Правда при загрузке страница на мгновение появляется в полном виде, но потом пропадает.